# Substring to extract before or/and after specific character in text

Tags: groovy, substring, indexof

I'm currently writing a groovy script that can extract characters based on the condition given, however I struggled extracting specific string after specific number of char. For example:

```
If (text = 'ABCDEF')
{
Return (start from C and print only CDE)
}
```

I already used substring but didn't give me the right output:

```
If (text = 'ABCDEF')
{
    Return(text.substring(2));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (text == 'ABCDEF') 
{
   return text.substring(2, 5)
}
```

`=` is for assigning a value to a variable.

`==` is for checking equality between the two variable.

Comment: Thank you, I know undestand how the substring (2,5) printed the right output.

Answer (score 0):

Your capitalization is all out of whack

```
if (text == 'ABCDEF') {
    text.substring(2)
}
```

There's probably also issues with using `return`, but that depends on context you haven't shown in your question

Comment: Thanks but this will print CDEF, however i was looking for how to print CDE only. It has been resolved for now.

Answer (score 0):

Your substring function isn't complete. If you need to grab specific indices (in this case, index 2 to 5), you need to add the index you want to end at. If you don't do that, your string will print the string starting from index 2, and then the remaining characters in the string. You need to need to type this:

```
if(text == 'ABCDEF') {
   return text.substring(2, 5);
}
```

Also, keep in mind that the end index (index 5) is exclusive, so the character at index 5 won't be printed.